# When i use regex_replace in procedure in snowflake not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace function sppi()
    returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var A= regexp_replace('Customers - (NY)','\\(|\\)','');
    return A;
    $$
    ;
```

```
call sppi();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your REGEXP is valid from the console/WebUI perspective:

```
select 'Customers - (NY)' as str, regexp_replace(str,'\\(|\\)','');
```

| STR | REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'\(|\)','') |
| --- | --- |
| Customers - (NY) | Customers - NY |

so in javascipt functions you cannot directly call SQL functions, so if we flip to a Snowflake Scripting we can though.

```
BEGIN 
    let A := regexp_replace('Customers - (NY)','\\(|\\)','');
   
   RETURN :A;
END;
```

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| Customers - NY |

where-as if you want to stay in Javasript, lets use a Javascript replace:

```
create or replace function sppi()
    returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var A= 'Customers - (NY)'.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
    return A;
    $$
    ;
```

```
select sppi();
```

| SPPI() |
| --- |
| Customers - NY |

Comment: create or replace procedure sppi()
    returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var A=new regexp_replace('Customers - (NY)','\\(|\\)','');
    return A;
    $$
    ;
call sppi();

Comment: select regexp_replace('Customers[0].value','\\[|\\]|[0-9]','') as customers; // this command is working but If I implement in stored procedure it is not working.

Comment: you first comment is proving my point. You cannot call SQL functions from Javascript.

Comment: `BEGIN 
    let A := regexp_replace('Customers[0].value','\[|\]|[0-9]','');
   
   RETURN :A;
END;
` works for me. Are you using classic console?

Comment: what is the difference between the select and call procedure()? If I use select it is working and If I use call prodecure() it is not working?

Comment: your original code you created a function `create or replace function sppi()`, you cannot `CALL` a function you use it, in a `SELECT function_name() FROM TABLE where function_name();` like pattern, in you example in the commends, you create a `PROCEDURE` now that can be `call`'ed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242749/discussion-between-divyacharan-jvs-and-simeon-pilgrim).