# snowflake regex_replace not working as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do this that strips "['" or "']" in the string.
For Example, if we have ['Customer Name'] it should be "Customer Name"

```
select regexp_replace("['Customers NY']","\\['|\\']","") as customername;
```

> I am getting this error--
> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 22 invalid identifier "['Customers NY']"

Comment: this is almost a duplicate of your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71403989/when-i-use-regex-replace-in-procedure-in-snowflake-not-working/71404042

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo..

ALL string in SQL are single quotes only.. you double quotes are for named objects like columns/tables.

Then you will have to escape the quotes in the quotes

```
select regexp_replace('[\'Customers NY\']','\\[\'|\'\\]','') as customername;
```

gives:

| CUSTOMERNAME |
| --- |
| Customers NY |

Comment: When I use it in the stored procedure of language "JavaScript". It is giving me the error `Execution error in store procedure SAMPLE: Unsupported feature '|'. At Statement.execute, line 22 position 31
`

Comment: Given this question was "how do I make this SQL work" this question has been answered, As to "how do I make valid SQL still valid when I embed it in a JavaScript stored procedure" that is another question. And I have given some guidance of that question also.

Answer (score 1):

Double `$$` makes escaping easier. Combine that with `translate` and you could do

```
select translate('[\'Customers NY\']',$$[']$$,'');
```